# How to animate a character applying lipstick?

Tags: animation, mesh

I could add lipstick to a character easily enough, in a few different ways:

A - UV mapping and adding a version of the texture image with lipstick on

B - Adding a 2-dimensional mesh for the lipstick and then using a shrinkwrap modifier to attach that mesh to their lips

C - Selecting  lip faces on the character's mesh and changing those faces to a different material

*But*, none of those seem to present any easy/feasible way to actually animate the character applying lipstick to their lips, which will require a bunch of frames where the lipstick is applied to *part* of the lips, but not the entire lips yet.

The  best I can think of is to use method B above, with the shrinkwrap modifier, and also add a boolean modifier to hide the part of the lipstick that isn't supposed to be visible yet. But that sounds pretty clunky to me, and that method will be difficult, anyway, because it may be tricky to prevent the lipstick from sliding around on the mesh when the character's lips move.

Is there any relatively easy and sensible way to do this that I'm not thinking of? (Other than just playing tricks with the camera angle, so you don't actually see it being applied, lol.) It seems like there should be a better way... Something like an extremely high viscosity and very sticky fluid physics simulation, maybe? If anybody knows a good way to do this, that would be a huge help!

Comment: I would try option D - Dynamic Paint. There are 2 textures (no lipstick & lipstick). Make the lipstick object a brush and the lips the canvas. In the shader you can use the paint/wet mask as the factor to mix between the two image textures.

Comment: Or even geometry nodes. Should be pretty basic with e.g. a proximity node.

Comment: Neat! Dynamic Paint seems like it would be the way to go. Never heard of it before. I'll have to look it up and give it a try!